# Can I redirect www.abc.com/a b c/test.html to www.abc.com/a-b-c/test.html with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am changing the way links show on my web site. I changed from allowing space in the URL to a new format where the URL has dashes where spaces used to be.

This effects only ONE string in the middle of the URL.

Google has indexed many of my pages with the old spaces in the URL but now they show up as 404s. Is it possible for me to put some code in place (temporary) that can redirect those URLs with spaces to the ones with dashes. I think it's a 403 redirect. A permanent redirect.

Thanks,

Comment: Just FYI you will want either a 301 or 302 redirect. 301 is considered permanent, while 302 is temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wen't through the same thing recently. We ended up creating a `LegacyController`, which basically called into `RedirectToActionPermanent` or `RedirectToRoutePermanent`. (HTTP 301 - Moved Permanently).

Ideally, [you should let IIS7 do the redirects](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/iis7-redirect-windows-server-2008), but we couldn't, because we needed to call our DB in order to figure out *where to go*.

If your redirect is as simple as you say it is (e.g no "dynamic" info in the URL), then you should use IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to configure you routing to support both: legacy and new routes?

Basically `/a b c/page` and `/a-b-c/page` should be mapped to the same action of controller.

Comment: Because I want Google to forget about the old route. I guess it won't forget if I keep returning a page. Then also there will be two pages returned that look identical. I guess that may also be a problem with google.

Comment: as for me, it would be difficult to make Google forget smth).. better support old, as it was before. all new would use new style routes